# ASP.NET MVC how to use pingfederate (OpenTokenAdapter) for SP Initiated SSO?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pingfederate

Intention to ask this question is how to integrate ping in ASP.NET MVC application i.e. Service provider? We have two idps (Identity Providers) and we have to implement service provider initiated SSO.

Let me know incase more details are required.

Comment: I'm not totally up to speed on my MS terminology. What version of .NET are you talking about?

Comment: .NET version 4 or 4.5. ASP.NET MVC used in the project is version 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start here from the PingFederate .NET Integration Kit User Guide -

https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/NETIK251/Processing+Overview

For SP-Init SSO, your application would redirect to your (SP) PingFederate Server which generates an AuthnRequest to the IDP. The IDP Authenticates the user and sends a Response back to your PF (SP). Your SP validates the message and maps the user's info into the SP OpenToken Adapter. The OTK Adapter will then generate a OTK and send it via the browser to your application to validate/consume using our .NET API for OpenToken.

Alternatively, you could check out PingOne Application Provider Services (APS) which is Ping's OnDemand solution. No installed software and a RESTful API to integrate your .NET App. However, not sure if your application is connecting to 2 different customer IDPs or 2 internal IDPs.

HTH,
Ian